# Differences between a 'local name' and 'qualified name' in a xml attribute

Tags: java, xml

Can you please help me understand what is the difference between 'local name' and 'qualified name' in a xml attribute?
From http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html:

```
/** Look up an attribute's local name by index. */
abstract String getLocalName(int index)

/** Look up an attribute's XML qualified (prefixed) name by index. */    
abstract String getQName(int index)
```

In this example,

```
<anelement attr1="test" attr2="test2"> </anelement>
```

What will be the difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The qualified name includes both the namespace prefix and the local name: `att1` and `foo:att2`.

**Sample XML**

```
<root 
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/DEFAULT" 
    att1="Hello" 
    xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/FOO" 
    foo:att2="World"/>
```

**Java Code:**

***att1***

Attributes without a namespace prefix do not pick up the default namespace.  This means while the namespace for the `root` element is `"http://www.example.com/DEFAULT"`, the namespace for the `att1` attribute is `""`.

```
int att1Index = attributes.getIndex("", "att1");
attributes.getLocalName(att1Index);  // returns "att1"
attributes.getQName(att1Index);  // returns "att1"
attributes.getURI(att1Index);  // returns ""
```

***att2***

```
int att2Index = attributes.getIndex("http://www.example.com/FOO", "att2");
attributes.getLocalName(att2Index);  // returns "att2"
attributes.getQName(att2Index);  // returns "foo:att2"
attributes.getURI(att2Index);  // returns "http://www.example.com/FOO"
```

Comment: Skeet's & your answer comprises the perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

A local name is one which isn't qualified by a namespace. The fully qualified one includes the namespace, if any.

It's probably worth reading the [W3C recommendation on XML names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) to get the full details.

Basically if you don't have `xmlns` anywhere in your XML file, you probably won't need to worry about namespaces. If you *do* have namespaces, you'll probably want to create a fully qualified name when checking for element names etc.

Note that attributes are generally less likely to use namespaces than elements, in my experience.

Comment: Clear-cut answer, but yet without simple example.