# Parsing xml: attributes.getValue() returns null?

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, saxparser

See this part of my xml:

```
<blocktype>
    <properties name="normal_blue" type="1"/>
    <resources image="brick_blue"/>
    <properties powerup="0" shield="0" />
</blocktype>
```

I'm using this code to parse it:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("level")) {
        block = null;
        inLevel = true; // parsing level
        Log.d("MyContentHandler", "Parsing Level = " + Boolean.toString(inLevel));
    } if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("blocktype")) {
        bundle = null;
        inBlockType = true; // parsing blocktype
        Log.d("MyContentHandler", "Parsing blocktype = " + Boolean.toString(inBlockType));
    };

    // handling level parsing
    if (inLevel) {
        int n = 0;
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("properties")) {
                int c = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("columns"));
                int r = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("rows"));
                bundle = new XmlLevelBundle(r, c);
                bundle.name = attributes.getValue("name");
            }// bundle might be null?
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("block")) {
                bundle.types[n] = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("type"));
                n++;
            }
    }

    // handling BlockType parsing
    if (inBlockType) {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("properties")) {
            block.name = attributes.getValue("name");
            block.type = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("type")); //nullpointer?
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("resources")) {
            block.resourceName = attributes.getValue("image");
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("properties")) {
            block.powerUp = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("powerup"));
            block.shield = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("shield"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything seems to work when I take away the second statement. As you can see my xml actually has the `type` attribute, still it returns null, according to the following logcat:

> 12-09 18:53:30.741: WARN/System.err(851):
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
>   12-09 18:53:30.769: WARN/System.err(851):     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:406) 12-09 18:53:30.769:
>   WARN/System.err(851):     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382) 12-09 18:53:30.779:
>   WARN/System.err(851):     at
>   cd.ark.utils.MyContentHandler.startElement(MyContentHandler.java:57)
>
> ...(sorry for formatting)

So basically it says Null is being passing into Integer.parseInt().

So could anyone help me with this NullPointerException? 
I've been stuck on this for a long time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of the tags is "saxparser", I'm assuming that's what you're using. In that case, the method calls seem correct, leaving the problem to be that `attributes` isn't correctly initialized with the values that your XML contains. Please add code to show how you generate `attributes`.

**EDIT:** The problem is probably that

```
attributes.getValue("rows")
```

returns null since you aren't using [qualified names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-using) in your XML; see the [documentation on the SAX library](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/overview-summary.html), specifically the documentation of [Attributes.getValue(String)](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29). If you use `Attributes.getValue(String)` and qualified names aren't available, it will return `null`.

A useful, but brief explanation of qualified names on SO can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429634/differences-between-a-local-name-and-qualified-name-in-a-xml-attribute).

**EDIT2:** I don't know how to properly adjust the XML (never used XML myself), but you don't have to use namespaces, you might be able to do what you want by using `Attributes.getValue(int)` since that doesn't work on the names of the attributes but on the list of attributes it holds. You probably need to figure out the order of the attributes though; you could figure that out this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(attributes.getValue(i));
}
```

Hope that helps; maybe you can find something helpful on namespaces in XML on SO; otherwise if your program requires the use of addressing attributes by their name, you probably will have to learn about XML namespaces.

Comment: Attributes is an parameter in beginElement(), wich is called automatically when parsing the xml.

Comment: Is the snippet above from the startElement(String, String, String, Attributes) method? Maybe it would help to post all of the method your code is a part of.

Comment: I think the problem is you're not using qualified names; let me just update my answer.

Comment: Pretty much hocus pocus for me. I believe I need to add some prefix right? Must I do this in the Xml, or in the code? I'm really sorry for sounding so stupid, but could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to do it exactly; my guess is that you can leave it at changing the XML, so your code can stay. I'm going to update my answer, just a moment. We can see if that works :D

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out how namespaces work in detail, so I couldn't adjust your XML as needed; see update.

Comment: Ok, I took your suggestion to use index-based values, which now works! It may be not as flexible, but thanks alot !

Comment: Wow i'm stupid, I had the same element name twice, both in my xml and my code... But ofcourse I'll accept your answer, I was just looking still :P Thanks!