# Get XSD type while SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, types, xsd, saxparser

I am trying to parse a XML document with a SAXParser. I have an XSD which the document validates against. While I am parsing e.g. in the startElement/endElement method I would like to know the type from the XSD e.g. xsd:integer etc. Is this possible?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attributes.getValue(String qName) method on the attributes object passed by parameter in the startElement method, to get the value of any of the element's attributes including the type: `attributes.getValue("type")`.

Depending on if in your xml you are using qualified names or not, you might have to use `attributes.getValue(i)`, where `i` is the index of the "type" attribute in the element' attributes list. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451023/3132058 .

You can find more info on how to use it in the SAX api [documentation](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29).